# How to apply my search on files with different extension in batch

Tags: batch-file

This batch code is to search all the PDF files in the path specified by the user and copy them all in the home folder and then deleting everything that is inside that folder (subfolders and files). How can I force my code to look for multiple files like pdf,txt and else.

```batch
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto :main
:main

setlocal

cls
echo.
echo Enter the home directory path where you want to apply the cleaning
set /p path=
echo %path%
cd %path%

for /d %%g in (*) do (
    echo %%g
    cd %%g
    for /r %%p in (*.pdf) do (
        set dest=!cd!
        set app=/
        copy %%p !%dest%%app%!
        echo %%p
        echo !cd!
    )
    for /d %%z in (*) do (
        rmdir %%z /s /q
    )
    cd ..
)
pause

endlocal

goto :eof
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:powershell-v2.0]? There's nothing PowerShell-related in this question. Also, `!%dest%%app%!` doesn't do what you apparently think it does. The files just incidentally end up in the intended location because you `cd` there first.

Comment: Another thing, `%PATH%` is an environment variable specifying where CMD will look for external commands. By redefining it the way you do you prevent CMD from looking for external commands anywhere but in the directory you specified and the current working directory. Do not redefine `%PATH%` in your scripts unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Ohh, my bad for using path as a variable name, thanks for mentioning it but I have a query that I have specified the scope to be local (setlocal) that still affects the environment variable (%path%)?@AnsgarWiechers

Comment: Why would you expect that to make a difference?

Comment: It will, but not permanently. That said, a bunch of batch commands are actually programs stored in your Windows directory and when you remove that directory from the PATH variable, you can't use them. In theory you won't see any effect, but in all likelihood this will really ruin your day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from doing

```
for /r %%p in ( *.jpg *.png ) do (
REM do something with %%p
)
```

The catch is that you can use any number of extensions separated by space withing parenthesis.

Comment: Indeed. Or put the extensions in a variable (`set "extensions=*.jpg *.png"`) and use that variable in the loop (`for /r %%p in (%extensions%) do ...`).